# A question about the number of chords in a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that there exists a positive constant $d$, such that for every graph $G$ with minimal degree at least $d$, $G$ contains a cycle $C$ with at least $l$ chords, where $l$ is the length of $C$, and a chord in $C$ is an edge in $G[C]$ but not on $C$.

The proof may need to consider a longest path in $G$ and use Posas’s Rotation Lemma.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have something that you want to add to your question, then edit it, instead of posting comments.

Comment: Interesting question. May I ask where that comes from? Also, have you found a solution?

Comment: @ManuelLafond this is an exercise in our seminar by my advisor. It seems that we need to use a result by Erdos and Posa.